# PyMongo text search using aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying a simple text search using the aggregation framework. I'm using Mongo 3.0.7

The database has a field named 'text'. I'm trying to retrieve the data from mongo using python. I'm using the code below. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

```
db.tweets.create_index({"text":"text"})
cursor=db.tweets.aggregate(([{"match": {"text": {"search": "cake"}}}]))

for document in cursor:
  print(document)
```

I get the error : planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it, i was unaware of the concept

BSON is de­signed to be tra­versed eas­ily. This is a vi­tal prop­erty in its role as the primary data rep­res­ent­a­tion for Mon­goDB.

My above code was generating in BSON format which is not in a human readable format. The mistake I made was to display it with a simple print.

Solution : I need to convert the BSON object to JSON and then try to traverse through the list.

```
from bson import json_util

json_docs = [json.dumps(document , default=json_util.default) for document in cursor ]

for jsondump in json_docs:
   x=json.loads(jsondump)
   print(x)
```